# how to create a dice iphone application

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I detect when someone shakes an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone)

i know there was many dice application in the store but i just want to know how to start to create a application ,when shake the phone the 3D model will roll,thanks if can give any pointer on how to start

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone) question.

Answer (score 0):

There are samples with the SDK from Apple.