# How to do: Shake your iphone to refresh feature

Tags: iphone

I want to know, how to implement shake to refresh feature. For example, facebook app, they dont have refresh button, on shaking the phone it refreshes the data.

i want to include it in my app. but i dont know what is the name for this feature and how to implement it.

can any one help me with this.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I detect when someone shakes an iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone :implement shake gesture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244227/iphone-implement-shake-gesture)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick search reveals this question:

[How do I detect when someone shakes an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone)

Then when you detect the shake you perform your "refresh" method;