# iPhone :implement shake gesture

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

In iPhone App How to implement shake gesture?

Please Help and suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find it here [How do I detect when someone shakes an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone)

Comment: from this link , answer given by : Eran Talmor works fine in my problem

Answer (score 2):

If your ViewController enable first responder

```
[self becomeFirstResponder]
```

and implement motionEnded:withEvent:

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
        NSLog(@"Shake is detected");  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the docs to [UIResponder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the [UIEventSubtypeMotionShake](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) event (from this answer to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170917/how-to-use-shake-api-in-iphone-sdk-3-0/1171386#1171386)).