# How can I differentiate a Shake vs a Tilt on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, accelerometer

I have a page UIScrollView that will scroll 1 page left or right depending on the tilt of the phone.

I would also like to implement "Shake for a random page", but cannot figure out how to do the logic for differentiating a shake motion and a x-axis tilt.

Can these two motions be used in conjunction with one another?  I don't need anything complicated like shaking while tilting, I just want both to work independently of one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect a "shake" you would check the g-force generated. It will be higher for a shake vs a tilt.

[How do I detect when someone shakes an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone)

You can definitely use both at the same time, just check the g-force for a high enough value to indicate a shake (> 1g - adjust to get the sensitivity to your liking), then if no shake is detected fall through to the tilt checking.

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone Application Programming Guide offers code samples for [detecting gravity](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedFeatures/AdvancedFeatures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH14-SW7) (tilt) and sudden acceleration (shakes)

Answer (score 0):

A tilt should never exceed 1g, while a shake can easily do so.