# iPhone tilt and iPhone shake

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am writing an application that needs to take certain actions based on iPhone acceleration. Having said that it also needs to make fine distinction between iPhone shake and iPhone tilt events. So if I know the device is being shaken (which somewhat implies tilting) I should only be taking actions for "shaking" and not for "tilting" and vice versa. Could some one point me in the right direction or provide some sample code ?

Regards
Viv

Comment: Please refer to this question it has the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019665/how-can-i-differentiate-a-shake-vs-a-tilt-on-the-iphone