# How to use Shake API in iPhone SDK 3.0?

Tags: iphone, accelerometer, shake

Apple annonced Shake API in iPhone SDK 3.0. I can not find any information regarding this new feature.

Who knows about how to use it? Any example, link will be good.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The APIs you are looking for are in [UIResponder](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/motionBegan:withEvent:):

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)motionCancelled:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Generally you just implement this:

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  if (event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
    //Your code here
  }
}
```

in your UIViewController subclass (UIViewController is a subclass of UIResponder). Also, you want to handle it in motionEnded:withEvent:, not motionBegan:withEvent:. motionBegan:withEvent: is called when the phone suspects shaking is happening, but the OS can determine the difference between a user purposefully shaking, and incidental shaking (like walking up the stairs). If the OS decides it was not a real shake after motionBegan:withEvent: is called it will call motionCancelled: instead of motionEnded:withEvent:.

Comment: Am I right if I say that we need to add the code `[self becomeFirstResponder];` on the view we require shake gesture to work?

Comment: You would be right in saying that. Also: (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {return YES;}

Answer (score 7):

I posted a complete 3.0 example in this thread:

[How do I detect when someone shakes an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone)

Comment: Keep reading, my response to that post does use 3.0.  I uses the events posted above, only I also explain the bit about needing to set the UIView to be first responder which is crucial to it actually working.

Answer (score 3):

Joe Hewitt recently [committed](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/commit/d674718e112d87e70b0d94120deadcb5b3ab0b4f) some code to [Three20](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/commit/d674718e112d87e70b0d94120deadcb5b3ab0b4f) that utilizes the 3.0 shake event. Seems like you just need to implement some simple code within [`-motionBegan:withEvent:`](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/motionBegan:withEvent:) inside of your [`UIResponder`](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
        ...
    }
}
```