# iphone App to use Shake

Tags: iphone

Can someone help me with creating an App which will increase a number counter when the Iphone is shaken.

Regards,

Vinay

Answer (score 0):

I think you have alot of reading ahead of you but the best way would be to find an example that uses the vibration sensor and modify it to your purpose.  Also,  I would try to find what API in the iphone sdk is responsible for this then I am sure you will find the functions you need for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be able to use

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170917/how-to-use-shake-api-in-iphone-sdk-3-0) for more info.

EDIT: That should help you handle the shake.  If you're still needing help with basic things like incrementing counters and updating the UI, I'd recommend the Pragmatic Programmers' [iPhone SDK Development](http://pragprog.com/titles/amiphd/iphone-sdk-development) book.