# How implement “shake to edit" in iphone program,the same as application icon in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

How implement “shake to edit" in iphone program,the same as application icon in iphone. Can it be implemented？

Answer (score 0):

UIResponder APIs. See this article:

[How to use Shake API in iPhone SDK 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170917/how-to-use-shake-api-in-iphone-sdk-3-0)

Comment: I think he means "jiggle mode". No?