# Acceleration threshold for shake versus typical hand motion?

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

What acceleration characterization should be used to differentiate an intentional single shake-to-do-something shake versus other typical random or unintentional device motions?

Answer (score 1):

Shaking can be detected by the OS itself. There's no need to do this yourself.

More info in this StackOverflow question:

[How to use Shake API in iPhone SDK 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170917/how-to-use-shake-api-in-iphone-sdk-3-0)

Comment: Alas, I do need to do this myself, as I am capturing other acceleration data, such as the axis of the shake and time between each shake.  However, I only want shakes, not "move the device so I can see it better", or motion due to the user walking, etc.