# How can i use iPhone's accelerometer in our project?

Tags: iphone

I want to create simple application on iphone. For this purpose i use accelerometer, my object is on the track and whenever it will go outside the track, it will detect if i moved iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [UIAccelerometer class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/Reference/UIAccelerometer.html). There's sample code as well (see the *Related sample code* section near the top).

Comment: Thax DarkDust... Now i am understanding the magic of accelerometer.

Answer (score 1):

Used Accelerometer reference from Apple. Thats really helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

copy and pasting directly from this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170917/how-to-use-shake-api-in-iphone-sdk-3-0) answer

The APIs you are looking for are in UIResponder:

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)motionCancelled:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Generally you just implement this:

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  if (event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
    //Your code here
  }
}
```

in your UIViewController subclass (UIViewController is a subclass of UIResponder). Also, you want to handle it in motionEnded:withEvent:, not motionBegan:withEvent:. motionBegan:withEvent: is called when the phone suspects shaking is happening, but the OS can determine the difference between a user purposefully shaking, and incidental shaking (like walking up the stairs). If the OS decides it was not a real shake after motionBegan:withEvent: is called it will call motionCancelled: instead of motionEnded:withEvent:.