# iAd giving problems with Shaking Motion

Tags: iphone, ios4, iad

I have an application that needs to detect a shaking motion to start/restart its activity. It is already on-Line, but now I want to add the new feature of iAd. I've implemented all the needed methods, but I have a problem: when I enter the Ad and then exit, the device can't catch the shaking motion anymore.

Ideas? Hint.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, actually I get the problem reading diggin into answers linked by Srinivas.

The problem was that when the Ad is end and returns back the control to my UIViewController, this one is no more the First Responder setted on his view. The solution:

```
- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner {
   [[self view] becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

In the below stackoverflow link:- [How to use Shake API in iPhone SDK 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170917/how-to-use-shake-api-in-iphone-sdk-3-0)

detailed info is provided. check this.

hope it helps

Comment: Solved and posted the answer. Thank you.