# shaking on 3.0 in a UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, shake

after reading some posts about implementing shaking on 3.0, I think I get the idea but I'm not getting any call to the:

motionBegan
motionEnded
motionCancelled

this is an example of what I've read:
[how to detect and program around shakes for the iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340492/how-to-detect-and-program-around-shakes-for-the-iphone)

I'm sure I've added the

```
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

and the

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
NSLog(@"First responder");
return YES;
}
```

Should I enable a special delegate for those events ?

I understand that those events are controlled by the system, and they are passed to the first responder, and go on ...

any idea ?

thanks,

r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had loads of problems getting this to work and I finally gave up and followed jandrea's advice. He suggested subclassing UIWindow and implement the motionEnded there. This is a quote from his post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone), look for it quite far down.

> First, I subclassed UIWindow. This is
>   easy peasy. Create a new class file
>   with an interface such as MotionWindow
>   : UIWindow (feel free to pick your
>   own, natch). Add a method like so:

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (event.type == UIEventTypeMotion && event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DeviceShaken" object:self];
    }
}
```

> Change @"DeviceShaken" to the
>   notification name of your choice. Save
>   the file.
>
> Now, if you use a MainWindow.xib
>   (stock Xcode template stuff), go in
>   there and change the class of your
>   Window object from UIWindow to
>   MotionWindow or whatever you called
>   it. Save the xib. If you set up
>   UIWindow programmatically, use your
>   new Window class there instead.
>
> Now your app is using the specialized
>   UIWindow class. Wherever you want to
>   be told about a shake, sign up for
>   them notifications! Like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(deviceShaken) name:@"DeviceShaken" object:nil];
```

> To remove yourself as an observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: This approach sounds great, and it's nice and very easy to implement. I'll give it a try!

thanks,

r.

Comment: I'm getting TWO calls from Notification Center when I Shake it on Simulator, but just ONCE on the device (iPhone) :-) thanks!

Comment: mmmmm, now I'm getting also TWO calls from notification center on my device (iPhone) ... should I remove the notification once I get the first one, and later activate it if needed ?

Comment: yes, this was the problem, If I shake too much I get too many 'calls', disabling at the first call and activating it later works perfect ...

thanks,

r.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you call `becomeFirstResponder`? You should do it in `viewDidAppear`. Does this get fired?