# How to make a web request with Apple's UIAutomation JS framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, ios-ui-automation

Is it possible to make a simple web request using the JS [UIAutomation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html) framework provided by Apple?

I tried couple of variations including browser's [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
```

and [node's http](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html)

```
var request = require('http')
```

But I am not able to figure out how to use either of them. Any workarounds that might work?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, or at least not in a simple way.

It can be done using `UIAHost` object, added in iOS 5.

Look this question and answers: [Issuing a synchronous HTTP GET request or invoking shell script in JavaScript from iOS UIAutomation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191814/issuing-a-synchronous-http-get-request-or-invoking-shell-script-in-javascript-fr)