# selecting next row of table view by shaking the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to change the row selection by shaking my iphone. 
i.e. as soon as I shake my iphone, the next row should be selected of tableview. And according to that another operation should be perform. 
can any one tell???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [UIAccelerometer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/index.html). Implement the [UIAccelerometerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccelerometerDelegate_Protocol/UIAccelerometerDelegate/UIAccelerometerDelegate.html) protocol, and do something like

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
  UIAccelerationValue threshold = 2.0;
  if ((fabsf(acceleration.x) > threshold) || (fabsf(acceleration.y) > threshold) || (fabsfacceleration.z) > threshold) {
    [self advanceRow];
  }
}
```

with an appropriately defined -[YourClass advanceRow]. Try out different values for threshold for a sensitive wiggle or a violent shake.

But also see this answer: [how to detect and program around shakes for the iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340492/how-to-detect-and-program-around-shakes-for-the-iphone)

Answer (score 2):

Apple's iPhone Human Interface Guidelines warn against defining your own meaning for the shake gesture:

> Avoid overloading the shake gesture.
>   Even though you can programmatically
>   set when your application interprets a
>   shake event as shake to undo, you run
>   the risk of confusing users if they
>   also use shake to perform a different
>   action.

For how to actually use the Shake iPhone API, here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170917/how-to-use-shake-api-in-iphone-sdk-3-0)