# Problem in Shake Event when using Flip View (IPhone)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I have a problem in reacting to a shake event. First problem is that if I place the shake view on root then it works fine, but when i flip to other views and come back it doesn't work at all. Second problem is that if I use shake and then flip to a view which has a UITextField in it then UITextField does not respond and no keyboard appears. I can provide my code if any body wants. Needing to resolve this issue badly.

Regards.

**Edit:**

Following is the code of root view (where i am using shake event):

```
enter -(BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder{
return YES;} 

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[self becomeFirstResponder];}

-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[self resignFirstResponder];

[super viewDidDisappear:animated];}
-(void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    if(event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
    {

        iv.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
        txtviewFortune.text = nil;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];


        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];


        iv.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);


        [UIView commitAnimations];


    }
}
```

Comment: @Wasim send code by mail or post your code.

Comment: @Wasim please post more code or send in email if you can. The code you have posted right now is seems ok.

Comment: what else i can post ? I am just flipping using the regular flipping code and then return on this view. Thats all.

Comment: @Wasim why did you write this code [self resignFirstResponder]; [self becomeFirstResponder];

Comment: @Wasim read this post it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340492/how-to-detect-and-program-around-shakes-for-the-iphone

Comment: I was just testing that [self resignFirstResponder] can solve my problem or not

Comment: Thanks for posting this link, but my problem is a little different from this one. In this example he isnt using any other views, he is just trying to shake which i already accomplished. I am facing problem when I come back on my root view after flipping from another view, then my root view's shake event stopped working.

Comment: is there any way to register the device for shake events again. like he is doing using NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: i dont know exactly, i only know that motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event responds on a shake event.

Comment: @Wasim if you can send your code by mail I can look into the issue.

Comment: its a huge code rahul cant send the whole code sorry. Can you just tell me that how can i handle this responder issue :(

Comment: @Wasim just create a demo with your flip side view and normal view where you are using shake motion.

Comment: I got the answer for my actual problem rahul . Thanks a lot for your help also :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use viewWillDissappear method not viewDidDissappear.

Comment: This worked for me perfectly

I was doing mistake in using ViewDidDisappear method, instead use ViewWillDissappear and it will all work fine :)

  ` -(void) viewWillDisappear: (BOOL) animated{
    [self resignFirstResponder];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated]; }` 

also you can add this line in your app deletage 

`- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
 application.applicationSupportsShakeToEdit = YES;
`    

Happy Coding..!