# does the accelerometer work for the iphone/ipad simulator?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-simulator, accelerometer

From what I can tell, my app should be firing accelerometer events while Im using the iPad simulator in XCode, but its not.

I have googled around and it somewhat seems that the accelerometer is not implemented in the simulator, is this correct? If so, why on earth would they have a "Hardware->Shake Gesture" menu option?

My code is as follows:

.h file:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIAccelerometerDelegate>{
    UIAccelerometer *accelerometer;
    //...other stuff
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIAccelerometer *accelerometer;
@end
```

then the .m file:

```
@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize accelerometer;
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%f", @"X: ", acceleration.x]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%f", @"Y: ", acceleration.y]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%f", @"Z: ", acceleration.z]);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.accelerometer = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
    self.accelerometer.updateInterval = .1;
    self.accelerometer.delegate = self;
}
@end
```

Does this look right?

Comment: The actions and gestures available through the simulator generate events, which are at a higher level than the accelerometer.

Comment: Why would they have the menu options then? Am i missing something? If it doesnt do anything, why have it at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no accelerator in the simulator.

The "Hardware → Shake Gesture" is generated by directly sending a UIEvent to the active application.

Although Shake Gesture is implemented using the accelerator on the device, conceptually they are two different kind of user input — the gesture is an event, the acceleration is continuous variation. Thus the Shake Gesture menu item exists for the apps which only use such gesture (e.g. Shake to Undo) but do not need to know the exact acceleration vector.

Comment: ahh, I see, well then thats actually what I want, so is my code wrong for that kind of implementation?

Comment: @Mark: Do you just want to handle to shake gestures? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone/1111983#1111983.

Answer (score 1):

Accelerometer does not work on iPhone/iPod Simulator. Neither "Hardware->Shake Gesture" use accelerometer nor the orientation change of safari on simulator.

Comment: sorry, how exactly do i do that? :) still new to macs

Comment: actually, I miss read your post, sorry, I get it now, so why have the menu option?