# Shake based application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

i want to develop an application which deletes rows from a table view when somone shakes the iPhone,can someone suggest me how to proceed

Comment: Step 1: learn Objective C, Step 2....

Comment: that i know my question is how to proceed

Comment: Look at the tutorials from apple showing how to build table based applications. Your question is way too general and you can solve it yourself by a little effort

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I detect when someone shakes an iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h framework and call the following methods

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {

}

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {

}

- (void)motionCancelled:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {

}
```