# Shake Gesture detection in UIWindow subclass takes over default text undo manager

Tags: iphone, uiwindow, nsundomanager

What I want is having my iPhone app aware of shaking gesture all the time except when any `UITextfield` or `UITextview` become firstResponder.

(I followed this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone/1351486#1351486I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone/1351486#1351486))

I subclass `UIWindow` and implemented `motionEnded:withEvent:` method and it works even if I set a `UITextView` to be firstResponder. My custom `UIWindow` calls `motionEnded:withEvent:` even if it's not firstResponder.

So the problem is my `UItextView`'s default undo manager does not respond to shaking anymore. The `UIWindow` takes over all the handling of Shake-Gesture regardless of how the view-hierarchy or firstResponders have been changed.

Could anyone shed some light on how to temporarily disable UIWindow's detection or have the current firstResponder takes over the Shaking-Gesture based on the implementation I have?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway I found a solution.

The default undo manager is actually still there saving all actions done to a UITextView secretly.

Since `UIWindow` takes over the motion handling, first I try to take it back by overriding `motionEnded:withEvent:` in the viewController that contains my `UITextView`.

Second, get the undoManager by `[myTextView undoManager]` then you can send `undo` or `redo` messages to it.

Now to mimic the default undo manager alertview, use `redoMenuItemTitle` and `undoMenuItemTitle` to get button title, then use `canUndo` and `canRedo` to decide whether to show button or not.

**Edit**: Here's the code from my application:

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (event.type == UIEventTypeMotion && event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {

        //textUndoManager is an ivar but it was just a reference to the undoManager
        //textUndoManager = [myTextView undoManager]; <--- in viewDidLoad:
        NSString *undoButtonTitle = nil;
        NSString *redodoButtonTitle = nil;
        NSString *alertViewTitle = nil;
        if ([textUndoManager canUndo])
            undoButtonTitle = [NSString stringWithString:[textUndoManager undoMenuItemTitle]];
        if ([textUndoManager canRedo])
            redodoButtonTitle = [NSString stringWithString:[textUndoManager redoMenuItemTitle]];
        if (!undoButtonTitle && !redodoButtonTitle)
            alertViewTitle = @"Nothing to Undo";

        UIAlertView *alertView;
        if (undoButtonTitle == nil) {
            alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertViewTitle message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:redodoButtonTitle, nil];
        } else {
            alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertViewTitle message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:undoButtonTitle, redodoButtonTitle, nil];
        }

        [alertView show];
    }
}

//UIAlertViewDelegate
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if ([[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:[textUndoManager undoMenuItemTitle]]) {
        [textUndoManager undo];
    }
    if ([[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:[textUndoManager redoMenuItemTitle]]) {
        [textUndoManager redo];
    }
}
```