# motionEnded not being called (no view controller)

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, shake, motion

I think I've done all I should to detect a shake, but `motionEnded:withEvent:` never gets called. (One wrinkle is that I don't have a `UIViewController` - my app is based on the "OpenGL ES App" template.)

I've added `application.applicationSupportsShakeToEdit = YES;` to my `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, and

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder { return YES; }
```

to EAGLView.m (which does get called), and `[self becomeFirstResponder];` to `initWithCoder:` (and have tried various other places too).

But the debugger never hits

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Am I missing some step? Do I have to have a controller?

(I'm using iOS 3.2 in the iPad simulator.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of the SDK magically fixed the problem. [Shrug]

Answer (score 4):

The way the `UIResponder` chain works with the shake notification is obnoxious.  Seems that `UIWindow` always gets the notification, and then sub-responders may or may not depending on whats above them in the chain.  I created a `UIWindow` subclass, and defined it as my window class with the following:

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    if (event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) 
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UIEventSubtypeMotionShakeEnded" object:nil];
}
```

Then, for any views that wanted the shake notifications, I simply had them add themselves as an observer to the `UIEventSubtypeMotionShakeEnded` event, and they got it every time.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(shakeNotification:)
                                             name:@"UIEventSubtypeMotionShakeEnded" object:nil];
```

Comment: a more indepth answer would be on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone by Joe D'Andrea

Comment: Did you notice you verified `event.type` against `UIEventSubtypeMotionShake` which is a subtype? By coincidence this worked because `UIEventSubtypeMotionShake` and `UIEventTypeMotion` have the same value.

Answer (score 4):

You must add this to your controller:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

-(BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This is correct way to do it. It worked for me. I had a problem because my view was in navigation view controller

Comment: this somehow messes up the repsonder chain for IBActions

Answer (score 0):

You can't become the first responder before your view is in the view hierarchy.

Comment: I tried calling it other places too but it didn't seem to help - like in `drawView`.

Comment: Can you create a view controller to stick the EAGLView in, and call becomeFirstResponder in viewDidAppear:?

Comment: I was sorta trying to avoid that if I can. `UIView`s are `UIResponder`s, if I'm not mistaken.