# Detect shaking method detect in xcode4

Tags: iphone, xcode

How to detect the shaking method detect in xcode4 and that method displays NSLog,

spacially i used xcode4 and detect the method of the shaking in simulator of xcode,

hoe to shake iphone simulator.

pls help,

Your regards

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I detect when someone shakes an iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone)

Comment: which is short cut key to shacking the simulator. and detec the method.

Comment: Dude, shortcut key is right in the simulator menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To detect the shake in your code you should use something like:

```
-(void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if(motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
    {               
        NSLog(@"DID SHAKE DEVICE");
    }
}
```

To simulate the shake gesture in the Simulator go to `Hardware -> Shake Gesture`

Comment: which is short cut key to shacking the simulator. and detec the method.