# view cant become a first responder

Tags: ios, first-responder

I have a view controller.  It is pushed by another's `UINavigationController`.
In ViewController.m:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder { 
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.view becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"%d", [self.view isFirstResponder]);
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

It's always 0. Why?

Comment: What is self.view? Not all UIView subclasses can become first responder.

Comment: is't a usual viewController's view. i'm trying to make a shake> useing that question: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone) It's just doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your view has to accept first responder status. This is implemented in your *view's* subclass code, you have to override `canBecomeFirstResponder`and return YES:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder 
{ 
    return YES; 
}
```

Comment: you'r right. I tryed to set this methods to ViewController, and this is wrong. now my ViewController.view IS firest responder, but shake doesn't work anyway.