# shake detection in iPhone which is presented as ModalViewController from appdelegete?

Tags: ios4, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, uiresponder

although this is a answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone). the solution works fine in rootviewcontroller of the appdelegate. if same methods are written in a  viewcontroller which is presented as a modalviewcontroller from the app delegate it doesn't work :(. can somebody help me out.

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer after breaking head for a day!!! (maybe a piece of cake for others).

here goes the solution:

In the root view controller or view controller from where we present modal view controller we have to detect shake:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //[self resignFirstResponder];
    /*dont resign first responder on view disappear */  
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{ 
       return YES;
}

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   if ( event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake )
    {
    // Put in code here to handle shake
     }

   if ( [super respondsToSelector:@selector(motionEnded:withEvent:)] )
      [super motionEnded:motion withEvent:event];
}
```

present the modal view normally... shake will be detected in modalview also...
Its tested and working!!
Thanks all :)