# iPhone app increase shake gesture sensitivity

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, shake

In my iPhone App I have used shake gesture it is working but it requires lots of efforts to shake.

Is there any way to make it more sensitive?

Here is the code

```
 - (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
      if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
      {
          [self performSelector:@selector(startPressed:)];  
      }
 }
```

Comment: I don't think we can change sensitivity of Shake Gesture.

Comment: Also to get more help, post some more code on how you are implementing it.

Comment: Check answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone)

Answer (score 2):

The isnt a way to do it directly as far as I'm aware.

One way to get around this would be to use the accelerometer's readings, and then decide for yourself if it was a shake, you would be able to fine tune it yourself if so.