# Change sensitivity of shake gesture in SpriteKit: goal is to create quicker shake?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Is it possible to change the sensitivity of the shake gesture in SpriteKit? Specifically, we want to trigger the shake gesture on a faster shake than the default. It's not clear from the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html.

This SO post is also outdated: [iPhone App increase Shake gesture Sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562168/iphone-app-increase-shake-gesture-sensitivity)

Is the only option to implement a custom handler using accelerometer data? Or would using gyroscope data be better?

Answer (score 1):

There's no setting for shake sensitivity. You can however use [CoreMotion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CoreMotion_Reference/) to create your method and set custom parameters for detecting movement/shaking of your device.