# iOS : How to detect Shake motion?

Tags: ios, shake

I added the following code to my appDelegate.m

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake )
    {
        // User was shaking the device. Post a notification named "shake".
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"shake" object:self];
    }
}

- (void)motionCancelled:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
}

- (void)shakeSuccess
{
    // do something...
}
```

and then I added :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // INIT THE BACKGROUND PATH STRING

    [self refreshFields];
    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    ***[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(shakeSuccess) name:@"shake" object:nil];***

    return YES;
}
```

When I start my app on my iPhone, the method named "shakeSuccess" doesn't called.
What should I do to implement this function in my app?
any idea?

Answer (score 59):

This might help you...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2405692/796103

He says that you should set the `UIApplication`'s `applicationSupportsShakeToEdit` to 
`YES`. and override 3 methods in your VC:

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self resignFirstResponder];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

The rest of your code is fine. (the `-motionEnded:withEvent:`)

Comment: Lol and he never did it.

Comment: Why call `[self resignFirstResponder];` ahead of `[super viewWillDisappear:animated];`? This seems peculiar.

Answer (score 26):

You could do something like this...

Firstly...

**Set the applicationSupportsShakeToEdit property in the App's Delegate:**

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    application.applicationSupportsShakeToEdit = YES;

    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Secondly...

**Add/Override canBecomeFirstResponder, viewDidAppear: and viewWillDisappear: methods in your View Controller:**

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self resignFirstResponder];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
 }
```

Thirdly...

**Add the motionEnded method to your View Controller:**

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
   {
    // your code
   }
 }
```

That should work if the first answer did not and this is only quickly typed not tested:)

Answer (score 14):

If you want to be able to detect the shake motion across the app, the best way is to override the class of your application with a custom class.

And then implement this in your custom application class

```
@implementation PSApplication

- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ( event.type == UIEventTypeMotion && event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake ) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"shakeNotification" object:nil];
    }

    [super sendEvent:event];
}

@end
```

Comment: This is the best answer for those looking for global in-app shake detecting code, not bound to single view controller.

Comment: In order to override the UIApplication in your main.m put this: `return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"PSApplication", NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));`

Comment: Why not subclass `- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` directly?

Comment: you can do that too i guess... :-) There's more than one way to skin a cat. But what if your UIApplication is not the first responder, would it work?

Comment: There will be two send events per one shake. Tested in simulator.

Answer (score 3):

I extended UIApplication class and added class reference to main:
MyApplication.h

```
@interface MyApplication : UIApplication

@end
```

MyApplication.m

```
@implementation MyApplication

- (void) sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if( event && (event.subtype==UIEventSubtypeMotionShake))
    {
        AppDelegate *objAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

        [objAppDelegate doWhatEver];
        [super sendEvent:event];
    }
    else
    {
        [super sendEvent:event];
    }
}

@end
```

And the last step in main.m

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([MyApplication class]), NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

This works in all cases.

Comment: Nice solution! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**Swift detect global Shake motion**

create custom UIWindow class

```
import UIKit

class CustomWindow : UIWindow {
    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard motion == .motionShake else {
            return
        }
        
        //logic is here
    }
}
```

setup CustomWindow

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: CustomWindow!

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

        //inti view controller as you wish
        //or if your storyboard has `Is Initial View Controller`
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: String(describing: SomeViewController.self), bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()

        window = CustomWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = vc
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```