# How to identify iPhone SHAKE in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

Hi I want to identify the iPhone SHAKE when user shakes their phone, either in background mode or in foreground mode of the app.

Please assist me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this will help :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154958/ios-how-to-detect-shake-motion

Comment: @PradeepKashyap i will check it. thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Refer below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503531/detect-shake-gesture-ios-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main trick is that you need to have some UIView (not UIViewController) that you want as firstResponder to receive the shake event messages. Here's the code that you can use in any UIView to get shake events:

```
class ShakingView: UIView {

override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if event?.subtype == .motionShake {
        // Put in code here to handle shake
    }
    if super.responds(to: #selector(UIResponder.motionEnded(_:with:))) {
        super.motionEnded(motion, with: event)
    }
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { return true }
```

You can easily transform any UIView (even system views) into a view that can get the shake event simply by subclassing the view with only these methods (and then selecting this new type instead of the base type in IB, or using it when allocating a view).

In the view controller, you want to set this view to become first responder:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    shakeView.becomeFirstResponder()
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   shakeView.resignFirstResponder()
   super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

Don't forget that if you have other views that become first responder from user actions (like a search bar or text entry field) you'll also need to restore the shaking view first responder status when the other view resigns!

This method works even if you set applicationSupportsShakeToEdit to NO.

For objective c version refer link  [How do I detect when someone shakes an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone/1111983#1111983)

Comment: ShakingView it is not a UIView at all

Comment: @Leo Dabus,  here's the code that you can use in any UIView to get shake events :)

Comment: ShakingView it is just a class not a UIView

Comment: You find mistake in code than you can edit answer @LeoDabus :)

Comment: there is many. you should test your code before posting

Comment: Thank you, see edited code :)

Comment: @Ashish Your code working pretty good. But i want to do the same in the background mode of our application. Is it possible to identify the shake in background mode as well?

Comment: @Srinadh, according to Apple's Background Execution Programming Guide, listening to motion events in the background is not supported.

Comment: Refer apple document link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("Device was shaken!")
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. i will check it.