# ios App check iPhone shaking and then take picture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, camera

I am writing an iPhone camera App. When user is about to take a picture, I would like to check if the iPhone is shaking and wait for the moment that there is no shaking and then capture the phone.

How can I do it?

Comment: Anti-Shake is much complicated than you think. So how about when the user shakes the iPhone you take the Photo after a 2 second delay.

Answer (score 5):

Anit-shake feature is quite a complicated feature to pull off. I reckon it's a combination of some powerful blur detection/removal algorithms, and the gyroscope on iPhone.

You may start by looking into [how to detect motion](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html) with the iPhone, and see what kind of results you can get with that. If it's not enough, start looking into [shift/blur direction detection algorithms](http://www.guthspot.se/video/deshaker.htm). This is not a trivial problem, but is something that you could probably accomplish given enough time. Hope that Helps!

Comment: +1 for giving a genuinely helpful answer to a really vague "do it for me" type question.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Ensures the shake is strong enough on at least two axes before declaring it a shake.
// "Strong enough" means "greater than a client-supplied threshold" in G's.
static BOOL L0AccelerationIsShaking(UIAcceleration* last, UIAcceleration* current, double threshold) {
    double
        deltaX = fabs(last.x - current.x),
        deltaY = fabs(last.y - current.y),
        deltaZ = fabs(last.z - current.z);

    return
        (deltaX > threshold && deltaY > threshold) ||
        (deltaX > threshold && deltaZ > threshold) ||
        (deltaY > threshold && deltaZ > threshold);
}

@interface L0AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    BOOL histeresisExcited;
    UIAcceleration* lastAcceleration;
}

@property(retain) UIAcceleration* lastAcceleration;

@end

@implementation L0AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer].delegate = self;
}

- (void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {

    if (self.lastAcceleration) {
        if (!histeresisExcited && L0AccelerationIsShaking(self.lastAcceleration, acceleration, 0.7)) {
            histeresisExcited = YES;

            /* SHAKE DETECTED. DO HERE WHAT YOU WANT. */

        } else if (histeresisExcited && !L0AccelerationIsShaking(self.lastAcceleration, acceleration, 0.2)) {
            histeresisExcited = NO;
        }
    }

    self.lastAcceleration = acceleration;
}

// and proper @synthesize and -dealloc boilerplate code

@end
```

I Googled it and found at [How do I detect when someone shakes an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone)

Comment: I dont think it will be fine enough for what the OP needs but nice find :)

Comment: Thanks but detecting the end of Shaking is complicated and a waste of time.