# CoreMotion's startAccelerometerUpdates:: not giving shake events

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I am  using following code to get shake events in my app using coreMotion FrameWork. This code works perfectly fine in iPod 5 but not working on any other device i.e. iPhone 4, 3gs, iPod 4. I tried in iOS 6 and 5.

```
NSOperationQueue *op = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        CMMotionManager *motionManager = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sharedMotionManager];

            motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1;
            [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:op withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error)
             {
                 if(error)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     [self calculateWithThreshold:accelerometerData];
                 }
             }];
```

Please advice what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@implementation ShakingView

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if ( event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake )
{
    // Put in code here to handle shake
}

if ( [super respondsToSelector:@selector(motionEnded:withEvent:)] )
    [super motionEnded:motion withEvent:event];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{ return YES; }

@end
```

I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1111983/1031955).

It works with all iOS with version 3.0++

Comment: I dont want to use UIResponder delegate methods as they donot give enough acceleration data. Thanks for the answer anyways