# Start application on shaking iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5, shake

I'm making an application were I want to start the application when user shakes his iPhone. Is this possible? Does any one knows how to detect this?

Answer (score 2):

It’s not, at least if we’re talking about a regular app distributed through the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible, to start the application using shake.

you use the shake functionality inside application

Comment: @user1926201 Some additon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone/2405692#2405692

Comment: @matt question about want to open the installed app using shake

Comment: I already knew that; What I indicated was some positive direction towards shake gesture.