# Detecting continuous/repeated shaking

Tags: ios, objective-c

An app I'm writing requires the user to shake their device for X seconds.

I tried doing this via `motionBegan` and it works sometimes. But sometimes either `motionEnded` or `motionCancelled` get called in the middle of the shake process, and `motionBegan` doesn't get called again unless you stop shaking completely. And there doesn't seem to be a way to detect whether the device is *currently shaking*.

There are a number of apps in the App Store that do this successfully, so there's obviously something I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motion events are discrete: Once iOS detects the device has been shaken, it sends the corresponding event and that's that—you have no way to tell it you're interested in long or short shakes. In fact, the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW21) says:

> An event is canceled if the shake motion is interrupted or if iOS determines that the motion is not valid after all—for example, if the shaking lasts too long.

If the basic shake motion events aren't adequate for your application, you'll need to implement your own custom shake detection using accelerometer data. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/159610/126606) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I have to use the CMMotion framework, as the accelerometer:didAccelerate method was deprecated in ios5.