# IOS Shake detect sensitive

Tags: ios, detect, shake

I use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationSupportsShakeToEdit:YES];` to detect the `shake` `event`.

But sometimes if I `shake` a little `too fast`，it seems not `sensitive` enough and can't response to shake movement. I even keep shaking and almost can't feel my arm...

Do I need adjust some parameters or I handle the shake result not correct that it still handle the last shake movement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there are no parameters to tweak regarding setApplicationSupportsShakeToEdit. If you want to adjust the sensitiveness, I would suggest the approach of millenomi who implemented the shake movement detection manually explained in the following SO answer:

[How do I detect when someone shakes an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone)