# Shake doesn't work when alert is shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uievent

I implemented shake gesture event. When shake occurs i do some stuff.

However if alert is shown I don't get event.

Here is what I have:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    // Register for shake detection
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder{
    return YES;
}


- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake){
         DLog(@"Shake ended");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get shake gesture when alert is shown ?

Comment: Implement your custom view looks like "UIAlertView"

Comment: At what point do you present the AlertView? is it in motionEnded?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 - (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ( event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake )
    {
        // Put in code here to handle shake
    }

    if ( [super respondsToSelector:@selector(motionEnded:withEvent:)] )
        [super motionEnded:motion withEvent:event];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{ return YES; }
```

Comment: Is it ok to call motionEnded directly?

Comment: I'd refrain from calling motionEnded yourself.

Comment: a more indepth answer would be on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone/1111983#1111983