# How to measure continues shake in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-motion

I have to measure continues **SHAKE** in event into my application. As **Accelerometer is deprecated**, so I am using **CoreMotion**. I am using following code into my application.

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (event.type == UIEventTypeMotion && event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
        NSLog(@"Shaking...");
    }
}
```

Its detect the event when I stop the Shake. Is there any way through which I can detect **continues shake event** ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you just tried with `if ( event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake )` ?? and also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone

Comment: Yupp, I had tried with it also. But its comes when we stop the shaking. I want continues shaking event.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the motionBegan method?

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (event.type == UIEventTypeMotion && event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
        NSLog(@"Shaking...");
    }
}
```

Comment: It will only call when we start shaking the device.