# swift: motionEnded does not trigger or real device

Tags: ios, swift, gesture, motionevent

I'm running my dicer shake app on Simulator. It does trigger `motionEnded` by doing shake gesture.
However running my sample source code on real iPhone 6 with latest iOS version, it did not help.
I've brought some parts from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2405692/1080355), but since I don't know objective-C syntax I could not completely translate all lines to swift.

Here are some pieces of my code:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) {
    application.applicationSupportsShakeToEdit = true

}
```

//
//  ViewController.swift
//  dicer
//
//  Created by eve on 2/23/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Hypersaz. All rights reserved.
//

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var randomDiceIndex1:Int = 0
    var randomDiceIndex2:Int = 0
    let diceArray = ["dice1","dice2","dice3","dice4","dice5","dice6"]

    @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView2: UIImageView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        updateDiceImages()
    }
    @IBAction func rollButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
         // A Block of Code
        updateDiceImages()

    }
    func updateDiceImages(){
        randomDiceIndex1 = Int.random(in: 0 ... 5)
        randomDiceIndex2 = Int.random(in: 0 ... 5)
        print(randomDiceIndex1)
        diceImageView1.image = UIImage(named: diceArray[randomDiceIndex1])
        diceImageView2.image = UIImage(named: diceArray[randomDiceIndex2])

    }
    override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
            updateDiceImages()
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool{
        return true
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        becomeFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with codes! I did need to shake my phone hardly several time to be trigger `motionEnded`.